# How to find URL between two dates in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, findall

I used `imageURL = re.findall("(https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/[0-9]+/.+)\?[0-9]+", urljoin(baseURL, image['src']))` to parse URL as below

```
<img style="width:100%" id="box_img1" alt="box1" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807240125_box_img1_A.jpg?1534992203">
<img id="top_img" alt="top" style="width: 100%;" src="//smtgvs.cdn.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808010125_top_img_A.jpg?1534994171">
<img style="width:100%" id="box_img1" alt="box1" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220125_box_img1_A.jpg?1534992203">
```

to

```
https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808010125_top_img_A.jpg
https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220125_box_img1_A.jpg
```

if I want to parse between 20180801 and 20180831, how can I modify re.findall() above?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of YYY1M1D1 and YYY2M12D2?

Comment: I modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

### Solving the original case

```
>>> import re
>>> links = '''
    <img style="width:100%" id="box_img1" alt="box1" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807240125_box_img1_A.jpg?1534992203">
    <img id="top_img" alt="top" style="width: 100%;" src="//smtgvs.cdn.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808010125_top_img_A.jpg?1534994171">
    <img style="width:100%" id="box_img1" alt="box1" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220125_box_img1_A.jpg?1534992203">
    '''
>>> re.findall("(https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/[0-9]+/.+)\?[0-9]+",links)
```

['https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807240125_box_img1_A.jpg', 'https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220125_box_img1_A.jpg']

### New case: to parse *between* 20180801 and 20180831

Two *big* changes:

1. `/.` to `\.` to escape dot character
2. Matches YYYYMM expressions matched by `201808`

So, the new code:

```
>>> links = '''
    <img style="width:100%" id="box_img1" alt="box1" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807240125_box_img1_A.jpg?1534992203">
    <img id="top_img" alt="top" style="width: 100%;" src="//smtgvs.cdn.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808010125_top_img_A.jpg?1534994171">
    <img style="width:100%" id="box_img1" alt="box1" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220125_box_img1_A.jpg?1534992203">
    '''
>>> re.findall("([htps:]*?\/\/[^:\/\s]+[^#?\s]+\/s\/topics\/img\/201808\/[0-9a-zA-z]+\.+\w+)\?[0-9]+",links)
```

['//smtgvs.cdn.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808010125_top_img_A.jpg', 'https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220125_box_img1_A.jpg']

Comment: YYYYMMDD1 and YYYYMMDD2 in variables, not fixed strings.

Comment: Ok. But you should give us more details. For instance:

1. What is the extension of the date range? Do you want to look up only inside one month in a specific year ( 20180801 to 20180831)? Or do you want a more flexible date range (20180801 to 20180815; 201805015 to 20180617; etc)?

2. Do you have a list of HTML tags or a unique string?